# Xcode storyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, storyboard

Is it possible to build an iPhone app completely in Xcode 4.6.3 Storyboard and deploy to the AppStore?

I am just starting an iPhone app and using Xcode for the first time. I have a simple app put together in no time using Storyboard and I have not written a single line of code. This feels like cheating. I have buttons on navigation view which I connect to views (Ctrl + drag - then use Push).

I run this on the emulator and all seems to be working 100%. Is there anything else that I need to do code wise for me to submit this app to Apple or has that all been handled by Xcode?

I look for classes that might be generated by each view but see none?

Comment: This may be less than helpful, but if the app works as expected and you followed the [app store guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/guidelines.html) you should be ok. It's hard to say without knowing more about your app.

Comment: What the hell is an *iStore*?

Comment: Make sure you include the appropriate custom icons; they're not a code or storyboard thing, but they are needed to publish.

Comment: Does your app only have image views or something? What does your app do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xcode builds the application completely to put it on the simulator, so in theory yes, it should work. For the classes thing, you generate classes independently of the storyboard, and technically the storyboard just calls upon the default `UITableViewController` (or whatever you have) rather than a custom subclass you might have.

About the submission, it is up to Apple whether they think your app is good enough to put it on the App store.

Comment: Thanks for this. All good answers here and all saying similar things. Maybe I sold my app short a bit, it doesnt completely do nothing. Its a tourism app for my local village, users will be able to see where to eat, stay etc. And there will be a map as well and links to hotel websites and telephone numbers. But my concern was just that Xcode Storyboard handles so much of the setting up for you that it almost felt too good to be true. I know Ill have to get my hands dirty with making phone calls and maps, but it feels insignificant as to what is done for me already. Thanks all for the help

Answer (score 3):

If it runs and compiles and follows the app store guidelines, you'll be okay. Just beware that Apple has been known to reject apps that are too slight or don't offer enough value over what a simple website could give. Any app that is just designed in Storyboard sounds at risk to be disallowed for this reason. You can submit it and give it a shot, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely build and submit it, although keep in mind that Apple occasionally rejects apps for not having enough content or functionality. If you built a pretty cool and useful app you should be just fine. If you built an app that only changes the background color when you push a button, or something of that nature, it will probably be rejected. Go ahead and deploy it to the App Store if you're happy with it, the worst thing that could happen is they tell you it needs more functionality.